# python cat (echo) equivalent for stdin

Tags: python, echo, stdin

I thought this program will echo my console input line by line:

```
import os, sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Unfortunately it waits for EOF (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) and then it produces output. How should I modify my program to get output line by line?

Comment: Are you running this under Linux? What version of Python? I can't get this to to break with ^C or ^D under Windows 7 with Python 2.7.2.

Comment: @Levon  Under Windows, the EOF character is Ctrl+Z, for weird historical reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 2.x:

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print line,
```

Python 3.x:

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print(line, end='')
```

See the documentation on [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) with two arguments, it actually has reading from a file like this as one of the examples.

Answer (score 4):

Python 2.x:

```
while True:
  sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.readline())
```

Python 3.x:

```
while True:
  print(sys.stdin.readline(), end = "")
```

When you use the `for line in file:` syntax, Python manages buffering for you, meaning you have no control over how many lines will be read before your loop begins to be executed.  When you call `file.readline()`, it will read a single line from the file and execute your loop one time.

Comment: Your code is correct, but you are definitely mistaken about the `for line in file:` syntax.  Python does not read the whole file into memory; that would be `file.read()` or `file.readlines()`.  `for line in file:` makes an iterator that reads one line at a time.  In this case, with reading from standard input, there must be some sort of buffering going on to cause this behavior.  Note that if you do `for line in sys.stdin:` it waits until you enter an EOF (Ctrl+D on Linux) and then echoes back; but then it is still waiting, and you can enter more text and another EOF and it will print again.