# Python child process loop over stdin from Node.js parent process

Tags: python, node.js, pipe

My *Node.js* parent program executes a child *Python* process and send to it text data - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713963/node-js-child-process-to-python-process) for the implementation. This works ok, the node parent process writes data as:

```
child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
child.stdin.write(data + '\r\n');
child.stdin.end();
```

the Python child process echoes it back:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ofp.write(line)
```

and it gets back the data to the parent:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function (_data) {
    var data = Buffer.from(_data, 'utf-8').toString().trim();
    res += data;
});
```

I want my parent process to fork *once* the child process, and make subsequent calls the `child.stdin.write();` without closing the stream. If in the parent process I do like

```
setInterval(() => {
    child.stdin.write(data + '\r\n');
    child.stdin.end();
}, 1000);
```

this will cause, at the second very execution a `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end` error, because of the `end()` call. While if I omits the `child.stdin.end();` I will get any output.
According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971404/python-cat-echo-equivalent-for-stdin) `sys.stdin.readline` will read line-by-line until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

```
def read_stdin():
    readline = sys.stdin.readline()
    while readline:
        yield readline
        readline = sys.stdin.readline()

for line in read_stdin():
    ofp.write(line)
```

the other approach was

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print line
```

In both cases I get no data back to the parent Node process.

Comment: You have to flush the stream for the other side to reliably receive the message.

Comment: @DavisHerring do you mean from the child process Python side? Assumed that `readline` will read just one line and I add a `while True` before, I should then write to `stdout` and then forcing flush..

Comment: **Every** writer must flush or close the stream to actually transmit (the last few kilobytes of) any message.

Comment: @DavisHerring right infact doing `ofp = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout); ofp.write(line); ofp.close();` it works for the first line I get the output, not for the next for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps the `close` is being propagated to the underlying stream?  Does the wrapper not support `flush`?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?